# How to connect raspberry to plc via Ethernet?

Tags: python, ethernet, plc

I have wrote a simple program using Python on RSPPi, that count time between the falling edges, signal is provided by PLC (Rexroth CML40). It works great, but now I want to send more signals from PLC but I don't have any free output spots. So, I think the solution to that is making a connection between Raspberry and PLC through Ethernet. My question is, what should i need to make to receive data from PLC (state of the 3 variables) to Raspberry?

I found this https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication but I don't really understand it. Is it Raspberry a server? Right? If yes then how can I make client code work on PLC... It is really incomprehensible to me

Comment: Quick googling brought me to the Raspberry Pi forums, where there are lots of topics on this. It seems that the good place to start is find out which protocols are supported by your particular PLC.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find what Ethernet-based protocols the L40 controller has available. [This sales guide](http://www13.boschrexroth-us.com/goto/edc/r999000027.pdf) shows that some of the IndraMotion software packages include OPC-UA, which is a good option because there is a robust Python OPC-UA library. Your controller may also have the EtherNet/IP add-on module, which would also work. Your distributor or sales rep should be able to point you in the right direction.

The second step is to find a library that allows to you communicate over that protocol. I've personally had success with OPC-UA, many options though. Some Recommendations:

- [Python OPC-UA](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua)
- [CPPPO](https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo) — EtherNet/IP